# Command Restrictions

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command won't work if it's not in a certain channel. When I run my code, I get this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!'

```
module.exports = {
  name: "kill",
  desciprtion: "idk",

  if (!message.channel.id === '794303555975643136') return;

  const { member } = message;

  member.roles.add('794308638125981726')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript and most other languages, you could refer to `!` in functions as `not`.

For example, let's take `message.member.hasPermission()`.
If we add `!` at the start, giving us:

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') return
```

We're basically telling the client, `if the message member does **not** have the administrator permission, return the command`.

Now, let's take your `if statement`, saying `if (!message.channel.id === 'id') return`, you're basically telling the client `if not message id equals to id return the command`, which let's face it makes totally no sense.

When we want to compare a variable with a certain value, we would want to tell the client `if the variable is **not** equal to value, return the command`.
Hence why, you should fix your if statement into saying:

```
if (message.channel.id !== '794303555975643136') return;
```

Sorry for the pretty long answer, felt like giving a little lesson to someone :p

Comment: I tried that and it gave me another error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: Well then, I believe you're missing a callback.
Is there a certain command handler you're using?